# Match exact string with fixed start and end using regex in postgresql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I'm writing an regex to create col2 and fill it with cp1 if respects condition else "not" if not.

The condition is if `f1== name***/state/` then `col2` will contains `cp1` else `col2` will contains "`NOT`".

I wrote the **code** below

```
when trim(f1) ~  '^name[^/]*/state/' then 'cp1' 
else "not" as col2
```

I'm getting bad results as shown in the attached images.

Does anyone knows how to solve it please?

Actual_output

[image: Actual_output]

Expected_output

[image: Expected_output]

Thank you,

Comment: Hello, please why are noting negatively my question? tell me if im not clear. thank you . (its my first time)

Comment: You should add full code / query what you have tried so far with problem statement. Also it is good practice to add sample data and desired output

Comment: Have you taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)? Have you visited the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)? Have you read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AkhileshMishra thank you for your response, i added a description to understand my problem. Please have a look on my original post . Thank you

Comment: @hamam i have added the solution with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should be `^name.*state\/$'`.

It will check whether string is starting with `name` and ending with `state/`.

so you final query will be:

```
select
f1,
case
when trim(f1) ~  '^name.*state\/$' then 'cp1' 
else 'not' end as col2
from table_
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=53e5ea339909797900660b33f0057e80)

Comment: @Matt It will comply the requirement mentioned in the comment [check here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a6f35d597d4dd8e8bd0291ac0a41ef1c)

Comment: My bad, got confused with the output, yeh your solution is much cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

I would make it simpler and use the `RIGHT` function.

```
SELECT f1,
CASE WHEN RIGHT(f1, 6) = 'state/' THEN 'cp1' ELSE 'NOT' END col2
FROM yourtable
```

Output

```
f1                  col2
name123/state/LA    NOT
name123/state/LA/X1 NOT
name233/state/      cp1
name1/state/LA      NOT
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/de7bbc/4/0

For a more dynamic solution:

```
SELECT f1,
CASE WHEN f1 = CONCAT(LEFT(f1, strpos(f1, '/') - 1),'/state/') THEN 'cp1' ELSE 'NOT' END col2
FROM yourtable
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/de7bbc/17

**EDIT**

Solution 3 to take into account `temp233/state/` :

```
SELECT f1,
CASE WHEN f1 = CONCAT('name',split_part(LEFT(f1, strpos(f1, '/') - 1), 'name', 2),'/state/') THEN 'cp1' ELSE 'NOT' END col2
FROM yourtable
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c82a5/1/0

Comment: Thank you for your comment. imagine that i have this case temp233/state/, col2 will contains cp1 in this case and its not i want, please don"t hesitate if you have another idea.

Comment: @hamam Please see solution 3